# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pin'

Tags: python, attributes, raspberry-pi, orange-pi

Can somebody please help with my code?

```
from pyA20.gpio import gpio
from pyA20.gpio import port

pins = ["PA7",'PA3','PG6']

gpio.init()

for pin in pins:
    led = port.PA7
    gpio.setcfg(port.pin, gpio.OUTPUT)
    gpio.output(port.pin, 1)
```

I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pin'

I think it's missing the command for fix attributes.

Comment: Do you mean to do `gpio.setcfg(pin, gpio.OUTPUT)`?

Comment: yes and also  gpio.output(port.pin, 1)

Comment: I mean are you trying to pass the loop variable `pin` in functions?

Comment: Yes, I want to use the string in attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to install PYA20 on my machine so i can't test this but, this could work out for you. You cannot append a string to an object. In Python the `getattr` method allows you to get an object's attribute using a string. Here's how it looks:

```
from pyA20.gpio import gpio
from pyA20.gpio import port

pins = ["PA7",'PA3','PG6']

gpio.init()

for pin in pins:
    led = port.PA7
    current_port = getattr(port, pin)
    gpio.setcfg(current_port, gpio.OUTPUT)
    gpio.output(current_port, 1)
```